# “Platz” vs “Ort” when used in the sense of “place”?

Tags: difference, word-choice, usage

What’s the difference between *Platz* and *Ort* when they are used in the sense of *place?*

I know each can have different meanings on their own (e.g. *Platz* can mean *city square* and *Ort* can mean *village*), but what when you’re talking about a place in a generic sense? For example:

> I know a place. – Ich weiß einen Platz.
>
> Is there a place to stay overnight nearby? – Gibt es einen Platz in der Nähe zum Übernachten?

In these generic cases, is *Platz* or *Ort* preferred?

Comment: And don't forget *Stätte*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Germans don't say "Ich weiß einen Platz." nor "Ich weiß einen Ort.". They say: "Ich kenne einen Ort."

"Gibt es einen Ort in der Nähe zum Übernachten?" is correct. (People understand that you're searching for a hostel or something similar.) If you talk about a "Platz" in regard to "übernachten", it's a spot to sleep (as in: "Du kannst deinen Schlafsack da drüben hinlegen."), not a place.

"Ort" is more like a location whereas "Platz" is more like a spot. But "Platz" can also be a town square, a sports field, or refer to a seat. To make things even worse: If someone says "Da ist viel Platz.", it means that there is a lot of space.

Comment: In some German dialects, it’s quite normal to say “Ich *weiß* einen Platz/Ort”, but it’s not appropriate in standard (written) German. _Platz_ is usually a flat area, big or small, surrounded by borders or edges, e.g. a surface to sit on (_Sitzplatz_).